# Can I get the successor of an universe in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm developing a library for googology in Coq. The project is working well so far. However, I have a question: Can I get the successor of an universe in Coq?

I can get the successor of an universe by `lsuc` in Agda. It seems that Coq has the only operator `max(_,_)`. By the `Print` command, I can see something like `Type@{(Top.9)+1}` that includes `_+1`, but I can't use this notation.

Comment: Why do you want it? It is not provided, but it's also usually not needed. Perhaps if you tell us your ultimate goal we can point you to a solution.

Comment: I'm interested to handle universe levels and constraints expressly. I become able to do by a notation `...@{i j | i < j}` which the Coq club thread introduces, now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot write a successor universe in an arbitrary context in Coq.  Only certain uses are allowed, such as entering the indices of an inductive definition.  [This Coq club thread](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2019-01/msg00048.html) discusses the issue in more detail.